# MYSQL join most recent record and multiply

Tags: mysql

I have a stock table and a stock history table, and I am basically trying to write a MySQL statement which will get the value of the stock on a particular day (in this case on the 31st of March), which can only be found by multiplying the cost per unit against what the balance for each item was on the particular day

So far I have :

```
    SELECT 
    SUM(tbl_stock.cost_per_unit * tbl_stock_history.quantity_balance) as total
    FROM
    tbl_stock
    LEFT JOIN
    tbl_stock_history ON tbl_stock.part_ID = tbl_stock_history.part_ID
    WHERE
    tbl_stock_history.date_of_entry <= '20180331'
    and tbl_stock.department = 1
    AND tbl_stock.qty > 0
```

Unfortunately, this code takes the sum of ALL qty_balances found against the part ID's history instead of just the most recent one against the booking_date parameter.

I have tried all the solutions I could find with sub select queries but none of them were playing ball and I feel like I am missing something super obvious!

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Because the latest activity on the Part ID might not be on the specified day, but the value will still be the same!

Comment: so each part id has the same quantity_balance each day? confused on the relation.

Comment: The balance column will show the remaining balance after the latest transaction - EG if 1 out of 100 is taken, the history will show that there were originally 100 and the balance is now 99. I hope that makes sense!

Comment: Note that `LEFT JOIN x... WHERE x=...` is the same as `INNER JOIN x...`

Comment: so you need to find the latest transaction which is <= '20180331' , not all transactions that are <= '20180331'.

Comment: Yes @isaace, that's correct :-)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT 
SUM(tbl_stock.cost_per_unit * t.quantity_balance) as total
FROM
tbl_stock
LEFT JOIN
(
 SELECT * FROM tbl_stock_history 
 WHERE date_of_entry <= '20180331' ORDER BY date_of_entry DESC limit 1
) 
t on tbl_stock.part_ID  = t.part_ID 
WHERE tbl_stock.department = 1
AND tbl_stock.qty > 0
```

Comment: Thank you @isaace, this worked perfectly! Much appreciated!

Comment: You are welcome! You can accept it by clicking on the check on the left hand side.